# Difference between currentSelection and activeMenuSelection

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

This feels like a n00b question, but I cannot find any exact documentation for this.

**What exactly is the difference between**

```
HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection()
```

**and**

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection()
```

**?**

Obviously both access different keys/variables in the Eclipse context, so the question is more precisely: what is the difference between these underlying variables?

According to my observations, in some cases, both can return the same object, but in others the return values differ. Can anyone explain the background or point me to some documentation about this? I have tried to search but nothing usable turned up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current selection is the item that the currently active part has set as the current selection using the selection service.

The active menu selection is the item that was selected to display a context menu. The menu might be displayed for a part which is not the active part or a selection which is not the 'current' selection.

`activeMenuSelection` is most often used for the `<visibleWhen>` section of the `menuContribution` element in the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point. `HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection()` is rarely used - in fact in the core Eclipse I don't see any uses at all.

Comment: That's more or less what I thought. But: If I am e.g., writing a popup menu item handler in the ProjectExplorer don't I have to use `HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection()` to get the element (e.g., IFile) on which the popup menu was triggered?
Backstory: In our code, we are using `HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection()` but found that this often returns the wrong element (namely that of another (active) Part). So for me the question is: why is `HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection()` used so rarely in Eclipse's code? Where is my error in thinking...?!

Comment: Thinking about this a lot of the core code is old and still uses the deprecated `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point and Actions which handles the selection differently.